# Call to a member function connection() on null in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am working on a multi-tenant application and one of the things I want to do is be able to switch DB connections on the fly when an organization/tenant visits the application by using their sub-domain to identify the tenant. I am using the multiple DB approach as opposed to the single DB approach; my implementation so far automates the configuration of the environment by creating a database for the organization when they sign up and runs all the necessary migrations against it.

The issue that I am having is related to resolving the `tenant` out of the IoC container and set the DB connection to use that database as the default, so the organization/tenant can have access to their data. This is what the `register()` method of my `AppServiceProvider.php` class looks like:

```
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    App::bind('setDbConnection', function($app, $db) {
        Config::set("database.connections.{$db[0]}", [
            'driver'    => env('DB_CONNECTION'),
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT'),
            'database'  => "{$db[0]}",
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
            'engine'    => null,
        ]);
    });

    App::singleton('tenant', function() {
        $server = explode('.', Request::getHost());

        if (count($server) === 3 && $server !== 'www') {
            return Organization::where('slug', $server[0])->firstOrFail();
        }
    });

    // dd(App::make('tenant')->slug);

    if (! App::runningInConsole()) {
        App::make('setDbConnection', [App::make('tenant')->slug]);
        Config::set('database.default', App::make('tenant')->slug);
    }
}
```

For the `Organization.php` model, I was explicitly telling it to use the `mysql` connection but I had commented that out; this is what that class looks like:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Organization extends Model
{
    // protected $connection = 'mysql';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug'];
}
```

What should happen is, if an organization come to the app, for example, `samplecompany.example.com` I would use the sub-domain `samplecompany` to look up the organization and then switch the connection to that DB early up in the life cycle of the app, so that the tenant can access their info. If I use the same `Organization` model anywhere else in the application it works perfectly, but when I use it here in the `register()` method of the `AppServiceProvider` class it does not resolve the connection any at all. The domain in this test was `http://bestfinance.global.dev:8000`.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1 FatalThrowableError in Model.php line 3293:
Call to a member function connection() on null
1. in Model.php line 3293
2. at Model::resolveConnection(null) in Model.php line 3259
3. at Model->getConnection() in Model.php line 1880
4. at Model->newBaseQueryBuilder() in Model.php line 1853
5. at Model->newQueryWithoutScopes() in Model.php line 1823
6. at Model->newQuery() in Model.php line 3503
7. at Model->__call('where', array('slug', 'bestfinance'))
8. at call_user_func_array(array(object(Organization), 'where'), array('slug', 'bestfinance')) in Model.php line 3519
9. at Model::__callStatic('where', array('slug', 'bestfinance')) in AppServiceProvider.php line 52
10. at AppServiceProvider->App\Providers\{closure}(object(Application), array()) in Container.php line 731
11. at Container->build(object(Closure), array()) in Container.php line 629
12. at Container->make('tenant', array()) in Application.php line 697
13. at Application->make('tenant') in Facade.php line 217
14. at Facade::__callStatic('make', array('tenant')) in AppServiceProvider.php line 59
15. at AppServiceProvider->register() in Application.php line 554
16. at Application->register(object(AppServiceProvider)) in  ProviderRepository.php line 74
17. at ProviderRepository-    >load(array('Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider')) in Application.php line 530
18. at Application->registerConfiguredProviders() in RegisterProviders.php line 17
19. at RegisterProviders->bootstrap(object(Application)) in Application.php line 203
20. at Application->bootstrapWith(array('Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\DetectEnvironment', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders')) in Kernel.php line 232
21. at Kernel->bootstrap() in Kernel.php line 127
22. at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
23. at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
24. at require_once('/Users/exampleuser/Sites/multitenant/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve the issues I had, what I did was to create a custom service provider (I'm also very sure this would have worked in the `AppServiceProvider` class provided) and move my `$this->app->singleton()` and `$this->app->runningInConsole()` up to the `boot()` method and I left the `$this->app->bind('setDbConnection', ...)` in the `register()` method. With all that in place, I was now able to load the respective test data for all my tenants seamlessly.

Here is my `TenantServiceProvider` class:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Organization;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class TenantServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('tenant', function($app) {
            $server = explode('.', Request::getHost());

            if (count($server) === 3 && $server !== 'www') {
                return Organization::where('slug', $server[0])->firstOrFail();
            }
        });

        // dd(App::make('tenant'));

        if (! $this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            $this->app->make('setDbConnection', [$this->app->make('tenant')->slug]);
            Config::set('database.connections', $this->app->make('tenant')->slug);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('setDbConnection', function($app, $db) {
            Config::set("database.connections.{$db[0]}", [
                'driver'    => env('DB_CONNECTION'),
                'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
                'port'      => env('DB_PORT'),
                'database'  => "{$db[0]}",
                'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
                'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
                'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                'prefix'    => '',
                'strict'    => false,
                'engine'    => null,
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

In addition, I added a `Route::bind()` to my routes file to handle situations where a person tries to load a tenant that does not exist. It looks like this:

```
    Route::bind('tenant', function($value) {
        $tenant = $this->app->make('tenant');

        if ($tenant->slug === $value) {
            return $tenant;
        } else {
            return $this->app->abort(404);
        }
    });
```

The original implementation for this approach on building multi-tenant applications was done by [Matthew Machuga](http://matthewmachuga.com/) on [Tutsplus](https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/building-multitenant-apps-in-laravel) in Laravel 4.2. However, I wanted to do something very much similar in Laravel 5.2 and this was the section I was having a little issue with. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Does the line you commented out `dd(App::make('tenant')->slug);` actually work and return a string? If you are then passing it into `setDbConnection` then `'database'  => "{$db[0]}",` doesn't sound right if it is a string, that would just give you the first letter of the slug.

Comment: No, it does not return anything, I keep getting the error highlighted above. I was just checking to see if I was actually getting back a value.